# How does Content and Product Staging in Magento Enterprise work?

Tags: magento, enterprise, staging

I've created a staging site (copy of the main site), then what I assumed I could do is edit a CMS page (eg. About) and view this on the staging site, then merge this with the live site when I'm ready to put this live.

What I've discovered is that creating a staging copy just associates the CMS page to both the main site and staging site, so if I edit the file it will update on both sites. This seems crazy to me and I can't work out how I can stage edits.

This is the same for products, where a product can be assigned to both a staging and main site, then if I make changes they will appear on both.

I'm not sure if staging is purely for new content, or if it can work with edits as well.

There is very little doco around this, and I've actually submitted a support ticket with Magento to see if they can come up with anything - but wasn't sure if anyone else had dealt with content/product staging.

Answer (score 1):

The staging functionality that was implemented is a bit hoaky in my opinion. From my understanding (rather limited admittedly) it creates a copy of a given website, as you noticed. You're then supposed to target modifications within the staging store/webiste scope.

For products, you would select the store from the drop down at the top-left.
For CMS items, similar depending on the whether you're modifying blocks, pages or other content types.

Once you've made the changes and you can then publish that staging site. Which will just update whichever records/entities were modified.